# Can't upload image using curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to upload images from my Server to another Server with php curl. I tested my script on localhost it works but on server it not working.

**Here are my steps:**

**First step**

I upload an image to my server. Path of the image is `"imgs/myimage.jpg"`

**Second step**

I excute this code for upload image from my server to another server.

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath("imgs/myimage.jpg");
$postdata = array('myfile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path); 

$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.secondserver.com/image.php");    
$data = curl_exec($ch);        
curl_close($ch);
```

This code in image.php from second server.

```
print_r($_FILES["myfile"]);
```

**I tested this code on localhost it works. But on Server it not working and display error.**

```
Notice: Undefined index: myfile in ....
```

I try to get full path of the image on the server with command

```
echo realpath("imgs/myimage.jpg");
```

It shows this:

```
@/home/admin/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/member/imgs/myimage.jpg
```

I'm not sure what it is about Permission? But I have also set up file permissions are 777.

What should I do to fix this problem?

I'm trying to find a solution for the entire day, but was not successful.

**Update**

I apply the code to test on another server. It worked. 
I try to get full path of the image on the server with command

```
echo realpath("imgs/myimage.jpg");
```

It shows this:

```
@/var/www/vhosts/myuser/mydomain.com/imgs/myimage.jpg
```

**I think probably about Config Server.** 
Should I set up?

Comment: Is there an error in the log of the second server (the one hosting market.kapook.com)?

Comment: error in the log of the second server is "Notice: Undefined index: myfile in ..."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you updated code for posting here but `$postdata` is never set before. In your 2nd line, you have `$postimg = array('myfile'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);`
and later you do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);`
Please use the correct variable (`$postimg`) and you should be good to go. Wondering how it worked on local :)

Comment: I'm Sorry. I put the wrong variable in my question. I tested it on a local it worked but on server it not worked.